# Correlation test with a few fixed columns in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation

I have an extremely large dataframe with around 30 rows but 30,000 columns and I want to run a correlation test using the `cor()` function. I want to ask is there any way or method to make it run faster (such as converting the data frame into a data table)?

**Edit**: Actually, what I want to achieve is for a very simplified data frame example below, I just want to find out if the scores have a significant correlation with `age` and `IQ`. The problem is that there are a lot, a lot of scores. So I actually don't need to perform all pairwise correlations (just look at each score with `age` and `IQ`) but I'm not sure is there any method of just looking at these correlations and their p value. Thanks a lot.

```
   name age  IQ score1 score2 score3
1   Bob  16 100      5      1      6
2  Paul  20 115      2      5      8
3 Betty  35 120      5      6      1
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Have you calculated how many correlation coefficients need to be calculated?

Comment: that's about 450 million correlation values.  What do you plan to do with the results ... ?  It's possible that `Rfast::corpairs` will help.

Comment: at the very least, you're going to want to do something to avoid storing both halves of the symmetric matrix ...

Comment: Updated with more elaboration on what I'm trying to do

Comment: So for `score1`, `score2`, ... `score30000` you could run a linear model `lm(score_x ~ age + IQ)` and keep the coefficients and p-values (if you standardize the predictors and responses the coefficients are *partial correlations*). Running 30,000 linear models is not terribly difficult with modern computational resources. There are **lots** of examples on Stack Overflow of people doing this sort of column-by-column regression analysis ...